# Disable underline for Markdown links

Tags: vimrc

If you have `set wrap` and there is hyperlink that is located in the "bad" place, you may see a long trailing underline after it:

[image]

Is it possible to disable underline for Markdown hyperlinks somehow, to workaround this visual bug?

Comment: The syntax element is `markdownUrl`; probably you could use `hlget()`/`hlset()` to remove the underline programmatically. Otherwise, `highlight markdownUrl …` with appropriate values would do.